# Hashing Algorithm returns \r\n at the end always

Tags: java, hash, base64, md5, sha1

I am using MessageDigest class to get hash of a string either using SHA1 or MD5. Here is a sample code using MD5

```
private static String applyHashToKey(String key){
        byte[] hashkey = null;
        MessageDigest md = null;
        try {
            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        try {
            hashkey = md.digest(new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(key));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String result = new BASE64Encoder().encodeBuffer(hashkey);
        return result;
    }
```

Now what i notice is that either i use SHA1 or i use MD5 the **hash string that i get in return from this function always has a \r\n in the end.**

For ex : Y60SedKVyEkKH4LKdikpc+zu5+0=\r\n

Any idea on what's going on. Is this ok or am i doing something wrong and introducing the \r\n myself?

Comment: I strongly suspect it's the `encodeBuffer` call. Is this the `sun.misc.Base64Encoder`? I'd personally use the Base64 code at http://iharder.net/base64

Comment: yes i am using sun.misc ...

Answer (score 1):

> Now what i notice is that either i use SHA1 or i use MD5 the hash string that i get in return from this function always has a \r\n in the end.

*Obviously* the Base64 encoder is supplying the line terminator. Otherwise it would encode it.